# Callback with NetTCPBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

Is NetTCPBinding supporting Callbacks? If so, please redirect me to any appropriate example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using [Duplex Messaging](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx). NetTCPBinding supports it natively, unlike with HTTP, where you need a special binding (WSDualHttpBinding.)

Comment: Actually, I need to create a chat kind app...(not bidirectinal). There is one Sender app will send to the wcfservice and wcfservice will trigger event at subscribed clients.... So i just need to push from One Sender app to multiple clients (not vice versa)...suggestion?

Comment: hi tomasr i am new in WCF...just learning. i have confusion that wsdualhttp and tcp connection support duplex communication.can u please tell me tcp connection support duplex communication or not??