# How config file would look at service end for multiple endpoint

Tags: wcf

i am working with wcf service application where svc file is created. now i want to design my service in such a way that people can connect to my service by http url and as well as by tcp url

so i would like to add three endpoint in my config one for wshttp, one for wsDualhttp and another one for tcp. so please someone give me sample config entry with 3 endpoints for wshttp, wsDualhttp and tcp.

in this case do i need to have three different mex endpoint for wshttp, wsDualhttp and tcp.

also tell me 3 url by which i can create proxy classes at client side. thanks

Comment: why did u clear all ur answer.

Comment: just see this url what tomasr said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212443/callback-with-nettcpbinding

Comment: another link http://wcftutorial.net/Callback-Service.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I was away and wasn't entirely sure about the `netTcpBinding` anymore. Reading up on it: yes, indeed - it seems you *can* use that binding for duplex communication - but that's one option that **doesn't** work in IIS - if you want to do duplex communication using `netTcpBinding`, then you have to use self-hosting. I've never tried or done this - so I was a bit surprised this seems to work.

Comment: thanks for coming back. IIS7 support netTcpBinding. if u search google then u will get many article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this (assuming self-hosting, since only then can you really determine the full service addresses yourself - hosting in IIS, the service address(es) are most determined by where your `.svc` file lives):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="YourNamespace.YourService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <endpoint name="Default" 
            address="http://YourServer/Services/MyService" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="YourNamespace.IYourService"/>
        <endpoint name="TCP" 
            address="net.tcp://YourServer/ServicesTCP/MyService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            contract="YourNamespace.IYourService"/>
        <endpoint name="mex" 
            address="http://YourServer/Services/MyService/mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint name="Dual" 
            address="http://YourServer/Services/MyService/Dual" 
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" 
            clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8001/client/"
            contract="YourNamespace.IYourDualService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This would define **three endpoints**:

- a HTTP endpoint at `http://YourServer/Services/MyService` for your service
- a HTTP MEX endpoint at `http://YourServer/Services/MyService/mex` for the metadata exchange (service discoverability)
- a Net.TCP endpoint at `net.tcp://YourServer/ServicesTCP/MyService` for your service

You could of course also use two **base addresses** to make things a bit easier in the config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="YourNamespace.YourService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://YourServer/Services"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://YourServer/ServicesTCP"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="Default" 
            address="MyService" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="YourNamespace.IYourService"/>
        <endpoint name="TCP" 
            address="MyService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            contract="YourNamespace.IYourService"/>
        <endpoint name="mex" 
            address="MyService/mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This would configure the equivalent service endpoints.

The `wsDualHttpBinding` is different in that it requires at least a `clientBaseAddress` for the callback mechanism (the WCF service will call back your client to send back e.g. status messages) - so it needs some extra tweaks and it cannot really be bolted onto an existing service that works over `wsHttpBinding` - it needs to be done separately. But *basically* - it's still pretty much all the same thing....

**Update:** after reading up on the topic (it's not something I use very often), it does appear that duplex communication is indeed possible also using `netTcpBinding`, but only if you're self-hosting your service - IIS doesn't support duplex communication over `netTcpBinding`.

Creating a duplex service does still require extra steps and extra code - so you cannot really have a service that's both non-duplex using `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding` and duplex at the same time. So it really doesn't make sense to have another endpoint in this example using the `wsDualHttpBinding` because that service either needs to be really duplex (then you can use `wsDualHttpBinding` and `netTcpBinding`) - or it's not duplex - then you can use `basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding`, `netTcpBinding` and a few more "exotic" bindings (like MSMQ, named pipes etc.)

Comment: thanks for good answer. u have given two set config entry but u did not said what will be three endpoint address for second set of config detail. would mine to write 3 endpoint address for second set of config entry.

Comment: how far i understand...u said a service can be develop for both endpoint like wshttp and tcp but wsDualHttpBinding not possible when service will have wshttp binding....am i right. so just tell me can not i develop a service which will have only two endpoint one is wsDualHttpBinding and other one is tcp endpoint?? say suppose i am developing a chat apps which will be hosted in IIS. i want that people can connect to my service using wsDualHttpBinding and also using tcp binding....is it not possible when service will be hosted in IIS? please help me to understand. thanks

Comment: sorry i got it...the URL's that the client sees are absolutely identical in both cases. thanks

Comment: wsDualHttpBinding and tcp both support duplex....so a service may have two endpoint for wsDualHttpBinding and tcp. am i right?

Comment: but i have seen a chat apps with duplex which has only one binding called tcp and was hosted in win apps...may be i am wrong because i am learning now wcf.but please have a look the url and download the apps and see the code for that chat and u would definitely see that it has only one binding called tcp and there was a callback technique...i mean duplex. here is the url http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application

Comment: so wcf callback is not duplex example ? duplex is something different? if so then i am sorry....because may be i hard something wrong.

Comment: @Thomas: updated my response again - and you're right - there can be duplex communication with `netTcpBinding` (if you're self-hosting the service) - that's absolutely new to me. But it still doesn't make sense to have both duplex and non-duplex endpoints mixed in the same service, since the service code itself must either be duplex (or not) - but cannot really be both at the same time

Comment: u define mex for http like "http://YourServer/Services/MyService/mex" but if someone want to create proxy with tcp binding then what url need to use to create with tcp binding that u did not say...probably missed out. waiting for ur answer.

Comment: @Thomas: usually, one MEX endpoint is enough - and the HTTP is usually the preferred way to go.

Comment: u create the sample config with two binding. so i have request can u put one more binding in it for wsDualHttpBinding. also tell me what mex address i need to use to create proxy with tcp binding and  DualHttpBinding bidning. thanks

Comment: Updated my top sample with a `wsDualHttpBinding` - and you only need **one** MEX endpoint - the information exchanged there includes **all** the information needed - the WSDL should contain **all** defined endpoints - no need for separate MEX endpoints for TCP or Dual.

Comment: if one mex endpoint is enough then how people can create proxy with tcp or wsdual binding specific? can u give any idea!

Comment: how could i instruct my client apps to connect wcf service over the internet using tcp or wsDualHttpBinding binding. i have seen one person design his config with multiple mex. each mex for each different type of binding.so i am not sure what will one need to make provision as a result client can create proxy using any specific mex endpoint. put some light if possible.

Comment: You need to examine the WSDL file you're getting from accessing a service - it lists **all** the defined endpoints (address and protocol). Pick the one you want. Or provide some **documentation** on your API help site to show people what endpoints are available