# Using Callbacks with NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to use callback like with WsDualHttpBinding in NetTcpBinding. Is NetTcpBinding support callbacks or events?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212443/callback-with-nettcpbinding

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a duplex binding over tcp. The TCP protocol allows duplex communication by design. It's not one of the [system-provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) ones but have a look at [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793.aspx) binding. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.compositeduplexbindingelement.aspx) you can find information regarding DuplexBindingElement.